# Asp.net C# cant see input text type using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I made login/signup dialog box using jquery but C# code cant see text box input fields , i need to get value from those text box fields using C# code 
Please Help 
Thank You !
ASP.NET / C# / JQuery

HTML :

```
 <header role="banner">
        <div id="cd-logo"><a href="#0"><img src="http://codyhouse.co/demo/login-signup-modal-window/img/cd-logo.svg" alt="Logo"></a></div>

        <nav class="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <!-- inser more links here -->
                <li><a class="cd-signin" href="#0">Sign in</a></li>
                <li><a class="cd-signup" href="#0">Sign up</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="cd-user-modal"> <!-- this is the entire modal form, including the background -->
        <div class="cd-user-modal-container"> <!-- this is the container wrapper -->
            <ul class="cd-switcher">
                <li><a href="#0">Sign in</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0">New account</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="cd-login"> <!-- log in form -->
                <form class="cd-form">
                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="signin-email">E-mail</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signin-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-password" for="signin-password">Password</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signin-password" type="text"  placeholder="Password">
                        <a href="#0" class="hide-password">Hide</a>
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" checked>
                        <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <input class="full-width" type="submit" value="Login">
                    </p>
                </form>

                <p class="cd-form-bottom-message"><a href="#0">Forgot your password?</a></p>
                <!-- <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a> -->
            </div> <!-- cd-login -->

            <div id="cd-signup"> <!-- sign up form -->
                <form class="cd-form">
                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-username" for="signup-username">Username</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signup-username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="signup-email">E-mail</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signup-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-password" for="signup-password">Password</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signup-password" type="text"  placeholder="Password">
                        <a href="#0" class="hide-password">Hide</a>
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="accept-terms">
                        <label for="accept-terms">I agree to the <a href="#0">Terms</a></label>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <input class="full-width has-padding" type="submit" value="Create account">
                    </p>
                </form>

                <!-- <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a> -->
            </div> <!-- cd-signup -->

            <div id="cd-reset-password"> <!-- reset password form -->
                <p class="cd-form-message">Lost your password? Please enter your email address. You will receive a link to create a new password.</p>

                <form class="cd-form">
                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="reset-email">E-mail</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="reset-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <input class="full-width has-padding" type="submit" value="Reset password">
                    </p>
                </form>

                <p class="cd-form-bottom-message"><a href="#0">Back to log-in</a></p>
            </div> <!-- cd-reset-password -->
            <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a>
        </div> <!-- cd-user-modal-container -->
    </div> <!-- cd-user-modal -->
```

JQuery

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var $form_modal = $('.cd-user-modal'),
        $form_login = $form_modal.find('#cd-login'),
        $form_signup = $form_modal.find('#cd-signup'),
        $form_forgot_password = $form_modal.find('#cd-reset-password'),
        $form_modal_tab = $('.cd-switcher'),
        $tab_login = $form_modal_tab.children('li').eq(0).children('a'),
        $tab_signup = $form_modal_tab.children('li').eq(1).children('a'),
        $forgot_password_link = $form_login.find('.cd-form-bottom-message a'),
        $back_to_login_link = $form_forgot_password.find('.cd-form-bottom-message a'),
        $main_nav = $('.main-nav');

    //open modal
    $main_nav.on('click', function(event){

        if( $(event.target).is($main_nav) ) {
            // on mobile open the submenu
            $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible');
        } else {
            // on mobile close submenu
            $main_nav.children('ul').removeClass('is-visible');
            //show modal layer
            $form_modal.addClass('is-visible'); 
            //show the selected form
            ( $(event.target).is('.cd-signup') ) ? signup_selected() : login_selected();
        }

    });

    //close modal
    $('.cd-user-modal').on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is($form_modal) || $(event.target).is('.cd-close-form') ) {
            $form_modal.removeClass('is-visible');
        }   
    });
    //close modal when clicking the esc keyboard button
    $(document).keyup(function(event){
        if(event.which=='27'){
            $form_modal.removeClass('is-visible');
        }
    });

    //switch from a tab to another
    $form_modal_tab.on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ( $(event.target).is( $tab_login ) ) ? login_selected() : signup_selected();
    });

    //hide or show password
    $('.hide-password').on('click', function(){
        var $this= $(this),
            $password_field = $this.prev('input');

        ( 'password' == $password_field.attr('type') ) ? $password_field.attr('type', 'text') : $password_field.attr('type', 'password');
        ( 'Hide' == $this.text() ) ? $this.text('Show') : $this.text('Hide');
        //focus and move cursor to the end of input field
        $password_field.putCursorAtEnd();
    });

    //show forgot-password form 
    $forgot_password_link.on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        forgot_password_selected();
    });

    //back to login from the forgot-password form
    $back_to_login_link.on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        login_selected();
    });

    function login_selected(){
        $form_login.addClass('is-selected');
        $form_signup.removeClass('is-selected');
        $form_forgot_password.removeClass('is-selected');
        $tab_login.addClass('selected');
        $tab_signup.removeClass('selected');
    }

    function signup_selected(){
        $form_login.removeClass('is-selected');
        $form_signup.addClass('is-selected');
        $form_forgot_password.removeClass('is-selected');
        $tab_login.removeClass('selected');
        $tab_signup.addClass('selected');
    }

    function forgot_password_selected(){
        $form_login.removeClass('is-selected');
        $form_signup.removeClass('is-selected');
        $form_forgot_password.addClass('is-selected');
    }

    //REMOVE THIS - it's just to show error messages 
    $form_login.find('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $form_login.find('input[type="email"]').toggleClass('has-error').next('span').toggleClass('is-visible');
    });
    $form_signup.find('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $form_signup.find('input[type="email"]').toggleClass('has-error').next('span').toggleClass('is-visible');
    });


    //IE9 placeholder fallback
    //credits http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html
    if(!Modernizr.input.placeholder){
        $('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                input.val('');
            }
        }).blur(function() {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
            }
        }).blur();
        $('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function() {
            $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
                var input = $(this);
                if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                    input.val('');
                }
            })
        });
    }

});


//credits http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/move-cursor-to-end-of-textarea-or-input/
jQuery.fn.putCursorAtEnd = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        // If this function exists...
        if (this.setSelectionRange) {
            // ... then use it (Doesn't work in IE)
            // Double the length because Opera is inconsistent about whether a carriage return is one character or two. Sigh.
            var len = $(this).val().length * 2;
            this.setSelectionRange(len, len);
        } else {
            // ... otherwise replace the contents with itself
            // (Doesn't work in Google Chrome)
            $(this).val($(this).val());
        }
    });
};

jQuery('#cody-info ul li').eq(1).on('click', function(){
$('#cody-info').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only html controls with a name attribute are posted by the browser . Make sure any fields you want to use in c# have a name attribute specified. You will then be able to access these from the request object in c#.

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls)

If you are using asp.net webforms or mvc then there is a mechanism to create form fields using server controls, or in razor syntax, that will include the name for you. You seem to not be using this but it is still possible.

Also I cannot see where the form action is set - how does the form post back to your asp.net server ?